# How to force a view refresh without having it trigger automatically from an observable?

Tags: knockout.js

**Note:** this is mostly for debugging and understanding KnockoutJS.

Is there a way to explicitly request Knockout to refresh the view from (already bound) view model? I am looking for something like:

```
ko.refreshView();
```

I understand that this is not an intended use of Knockout, but I still want to know if there is a such method for debugging and learning purposes.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You can't call something on the entire viewModel, but on an individual observable you can call `myObservable.valueHasMutated()` to notify subscribers that they should re-evaluate.  This is generally not necessary in KO, as you mentioned.

Comment: You can also iterate over the data context, searching for elements that have a `valueHasMutated` property which is of type `function` and calling it for each of them. That should get all of your observables, but it's bad practice and conceivably fire off a whole lot more updates than you anticipate (think computed dependency chains).

Comment: It sure would be nice if for nothing else - testing in chrome.

Comment: Your viewModel can, itself, be an observable, so you could call `myViewModel.valueHasMutated()` to update the whole view.

Comment: Doesn't work on arrays here either. In fact arrays don't seem to work at all in Knockout. I miss Angular :-(

Comment: It does work on KnockoutObservableArrays as of KO 3.5

Comment: There is a "dirty refresh" method for when `valueHasMutated` doesn't work on an observableArray, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13231783/3437953

Answer (score 25):

In some circumstances it might be useful to simply remove the bindings and then re-apply:

```
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById(element_id))
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById(element_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit ebram... Guess I should've mentioned I use coffeescript ;-)

Comment: Watch out if you also use jQuery (e.g. when migrating bits of the app to ko) as cleanNode will also remove other dom events.

Comment: This is perfect. I can't get KO to recognize NEW dom children with data-bind attributes after a viewmodel has been applied.

Comment: Perfect! Working!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a JSFiddle with my bindHTML knockout binding handler here:
https://jsfiddle.net/glaivier/9859uq8t/

First, save the binding handler into its own (or a common) file and include after Knockout.

If you use this switch your bindings to this:

```
<div data-bind="bindHTML: htmlValue"></div>

OR

<!-- ko bindHTML: htmlValue --><!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative is to clear the observable array:

```
let tmp = myObservableArray();
myObservableArray([]);
myObservableArray(tmp);
```

Note: This alternative could perhaps suffer in performance.