# Knockout JS not updating when changing array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know this was asked multiple times already, but none of that answered my question.
I have the following:
I get data over JSON to Javascript into a two dimensional array.
When I load the site, the table shows up like wanted.
Now when I click a button (just for testing), it is updating one value from the array and logging that array in the console, where I see the changed array.
The problem is that the change is not showing up in the table.
When I just add a value to the array, it is showing up in the table.
What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<table id="sortsTable">
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: sorts">
   <tr>
     <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: $data.ingName"></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: addPerson">Add</button>
```

JS:

```
var sorts = ko.observableArray([]);

$(function() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = new FormData();
var responseElements = [];
request.open("POST", "scripts.php", true);
formData.append("action", "getSorts");
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        responseElements = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        sorts = convertList(responseElements);
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(sorts));
    }
}
request.send(formData);

});

function convertList(response) {  //just the function to convert the json object to a more useful array
    var names = [];
    var ingredients = [];
    var sorts = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
        var name = response[index]['name'];
        var ing = response[index]['ingName'];
        if (names.indexOf(name) == -1) {
            names.push(name);
        }
        if (ingredients.indexOf(ing) == -1) {
            var nameIndex = names.indexOf(name);
            if (ingredients[nameIndex] == undefined) {
                ingredients[nameIndex] = ing;
            } else {
                ingredients[nameIndex] = ingredients[nameIndex] + ", " + ing;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        sorts[i] = {};
        sorts[i]['name'] = names[i];
        sorts[i]['ingName'] = ingredients[i];
    }
    return sorts;
}

function AppViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.sorts = data;
    self.addPerson = function() {
        console.log("click");
        self.sorts[0]["name"] = "test";  //doesn't update table
        //self.sorts.push({name: "qwer", ingName: "we"});  //works like expected
        console.log(self.sorts);
    };
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably what's happening is that knockout.js is monitoring changes to the array, but not updates to the variables. When you add a new element, you're changing the contents of the array, but when you update an element, you're mutating a variable, but the array can retain all the same pointers to variables it already has. You'll likely need to fire a refresh event in knockout.

Comment: Yes it doesn't look like you're using any observables? Which really makes using knockout pointless. I suggest you read some knockout tutorials

Comment: @JasonSpake i am using an observable array. look at the beginning of the code. Am I not doing it right?

Comment: @tswei how should I do this refreshing?

Comment: You might try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231738/refresh-observablearray-when-items-are-not-observables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observable array only monitors which items are added to it, not the items themselves, so

```
self.sorts.push({name: "qwer", ingName: "we"});  //works like expected
```

works because you're getting the observable array to add to it's items, but

```
self.sorts[0]["name"] = "test";  //doesn't update table
```

doesn't work because the observable array has no way of knowing that an item inside it has changed. For this to work the properties of the items in the array will need to be observable.

In convertList switch to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    sorts[i] = {};
    sorts[i]['name'] = ko.observable(names[i]);
    sorts[i]['ingName'] = ko.observable(ingredients[i]);
}
```

And they must be set by calling the observable setter method like so:

```
self.addPerson = function() {
    console.log("click");
    self.sorts[0]["name"]("test");
    ...
```

Also as an aside, you seem to have some other issues here. You define sorts as an observable array on the first line, but you overwrite it with the return value of convertList which is a normal array, not an observable one.

```
sorts = convertList(responseElements);
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(sorts));
```

I'd remove the first line and create sorts as an observable array

```
function convertList(response) {  //just the function to convert the json object to a more useful array
    var names = [];
    var ingredients = [];
    var sorts = ko.observableArray([]);
    ...
```

Comment: In convertList switch to:

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    sorts[i] = {};
    sorts[i]['name'] = ko.observable(names[i]);
    sorts[i]['ingName'] = ko.observable(ingredients[i]);
}

this doesn't work, because when initializing an observable array, the argument must be an array, not a value...

Comment: But we're not initialising observable arrays here, we're initialising observables.

Comment: well, right, didn't see that I guess.
I changed it, now for some reason the array is empty.. so it doesn't output anything at all

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you bind this:

```
 <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
```

`$data.name` is not observable, it's a simple property on an object, created here:

```
sorts[i]['name'] = names[i];
```

Knockout will quite happily bind properties like this, and display them, but any updates to them are not visible to knockout.  Instead, as well as your `observableArray`, you also need to make any individual properties you want the ability to update observable as well:

```
sorts[i]['name'] = ko.observable(names[i]);
```

Then when you update it, knockout will see the change.  Note however that you can't simply just assign to the property, as you'll just overwrite the knockout observable and it will be lost, instead you need to *call* the observable with the update:

```
self.sorts[0]["name"]("test");
```