# Sorting and filtering not working in knockout kendo grid

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, knockout-kendo

I am using Knockout-Kendo.js and i had no problems binding data to the grid and seeing changes when observable array changes.

However

1. Sorting does not work and there are no js errors.

Please note that tasks is a ko.observableArray()

```
        <div data-bind="kendoGrid: {
                data: tasks,
                columns: [
                    { field: 'TaskId', title: 'Task Id' },
                    { field: 'Description', title: 'Description' },
                    { field: 'RaisedBy', title: 'Requested User' },
                    { field: 'Status', title: 'Status' },
                    { field: '', title: '' }
                ],
                rowTemplate: 'Template',
                useKOTemplates: true,
                editable: false,
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                scrollable: false,
                pageable: {pageSize: 5 }
                }">
        </div>


<script id="Template" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td><div data-bind="text: TaskId"></div></td>
        <td><div data-bind="text: Description"></div></td>            
        <td><div data-bind="text: RaisedBy"></div></td>            
        <td><div data-bind="text: Status"></div></td>
        <td><button data-bind="click: $root.viewDetails">View</button></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

1. Filtering does not work either and this is what i see in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  (anonymous function)
>   VM3445:3 o.filter kendo.web.min.js:11 o.process kendo.web.min.js:11
>   ct.extend.query kendo.web.min.js:11 ct.extend._query
>   kendo.web.min.js:11 ct.extend.filter kendo.web.min.js:11
>   g.extend.filter kendo.web.min.js:19 g.extend._submit
>   kendo.web.min.js:19 b.extend.proxy.b.isFunction.i jquery-1.9.1.js:7223
>   b.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:9593

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fc0ukq9o/

I found that the JSFiddle works without any problem, with the observable array.

However in my case the observable array was getting populated by the below code, which  automatically creates observable properties for each of the properties on data. After this i can see that the sort and filter stops working.

```
$.each(data.source, function (index, data) {
                    self.tasks.push(ko.mapping.fromJS({
                        TaskId: data.TaskId,
                        Description: data.Description,
                        RaisedBy: data.RaisedBy,
                        Status: data.Status
                    }));
                });
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you have. Can you post your view model and sample data or replicate the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the original question with further information.

Comment: your jsfiddle works fine here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that was tough one, but I guess I solved it, see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6j2qkb9a/3/).

The problem with your approach is that Kendo knows nothing about KO observables, and knockout-kendo just passes data as plain JS object to Kendo. So if you want to be able to change data in your table, you should use some workaround. My approach was to use [`valueHasMutated`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537397/knockout-js-how-to-force-view-refresh-instead-of-using-ko-observable) method to tell knockout that task in tasks array was updated.

Here is how view model looks like:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray();
    self.viewDetails = function(data) {
        alert(data.TaskId);
    };
    self.changeData = function() {
        self.tasks()[0].TaskId = 3;
        self.tasks.valueHasMutated(); // this will tell knockout that tasks were changed
    }
};
```

`tasks` is an observable array of Task objects:

```
function Task(id, description, raisedBy, status) {
    this.TaskId = id;
    this.Description = description;
    this.RaisedBy = raisedBy;
    this.Status = status;
};
```

I also added initialisation method that has dummy data:

```
ViewModel.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    var data = {
        source: [
            new Task(1, "Task 1", "User 1", "New"),
            new Task(2, "Task 2", "User 2", "Closed"),
            new Task(3, "Task 3", "User 3", "In progress"),
            new Task(4, "Task 4", "User 4", "New"),
            new Task(5, "Task 5", "User 5", "In progress")
        ]
    };
    self.tasks(data.source);
}
```

So now sorting works as it should, and in case you change some of the tasks (press "Change data" button in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j2qkb9a/3/)), table is refreshed.

Comment: Did you test that with a larger array? valueHasMutated causes knockout-kendo to reload the data source, so I expect a performance trap!