# Knockout pure computed observable not updating

Tags: knockout.js

Having the following model:

```
  var dataModel = ko.observable({ someProp: ko.observable() });

  var isValid = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return dataModel().isValid;
  });
```

I have the following function:

```
      function testMe() {
          dataModel().isValid = false; // This does not work, why?
          console.log("isValid: " + isValid()); // Doesn't update, shows old value 

          dataModel({ isValid: false }); // This works however I loose all other properties
          console.log("isValid: " + isValid()); // Prints correctly updated value

          console.log(ko.toJSON(dataModel()));          
      }
```

Whenever I run testMe()

> dataModel.isValid = false

and execute

> console.log("isValid: " + isValid())

it's still set to "true" even I've set it to false above...why?. The only way I got it to work is to do

> dataModel({ isValid: false });
>   however this way I loose all other properties in my model. How can I make this work?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If I run your code with I do not see "true" in any instance, see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fdyyhr2/), could you please try to create an "[mcve]" and explain *why* you expect said results?

Comment: Also, realize that if a (pure)computed depends on a variable that is *not* observable, it might not get updated correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isValid` is not an observable. A computed will only know to update if one of its observables has changed. Alternatively, you can tell Knockout that `dataModel` has changed (which, being an observable that the computed looks at, will cause the computed to recompute) using [`dataModel.valueHasMutated()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537771/392102).

I would recommend using an observable, though. Try something like this:

```js
var dataModel = ko.observable({
  someProp: ko.observable(),
  isValid: ko.observable(true)
});

var isValid = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return dataModel().isValid();
});

function testMe() {
  console.log("isValid: " + isValid());
  dataModel().isValid(false);
  console.log("isValid: " + isValid());

  console.log(ko.toJSON(dataModel()));
}

testMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: right on the money. thanks so much!. Also, a question. why does @Jeroen's example works even though isValid is not an observable? https://jsfiddle.net/8fdyyhr2/

Comment: @ShaneKm In his example, the value of `isValid` never changes. It starts false and stays false. That was what his comment was saying.